# Text under an Image button

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text on an Image button in c# asp.net 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262141/text-on-an-image-button-in-c-sharp-asp-net-3-5)

I have an image button. I want to add a text under it. I'm using VS 2010. Can anyone tell me how to add text to a image button??

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/Icon_Variante1.jpg" />
```

Comment: define "under it". Do you mean add to the same button over the image? Or a separate element after/below this image button?

Comment: Is it necessary to use image button ?
You can use normal button set text and also set backgroung image using css

Comment: The first result from StackOverflow: 
[Workaround here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262141/text-on-an-image-button-in-c-sharp-asp-net-3-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add text **under** the button, you should add a label after the button. Then put the label and the button into a container and change styles for it. An example below

```
    <div style="width:100px;">
        <div>
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="BUTTON" ImageUrl="IMAGE_URL" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="TEXT FOR BUTTON"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add text to an image button. If you want to add some under it, add a label control to the required position.

Answer (score 0):

```
.btnBg
{
   background:url("../imagepath");
}

<asp:Button ID="Button2" CssClass="btnBg" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```