# Adding Image Caption

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have images displayed from a folder and with the help of the function below i am able to do just that.

```
private void LoadImages()
{
    foreach (string strfile in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Data")))
    {
        ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(strfile);
        imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/Data/" + fi.Name;
        imageButton.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
        imageButton.Style.Add("padding", "5px");
        imageButton.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
        imageButton.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imageButton_Click);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(imageButton);

    }
}
```

Guys! i need to display the name of the image below the image. Help Please!

Comment: The problem is i need the name of the image to be displayed below it.

Comment: If ImageButton doesn't have a property that allows you to do this, then you'll need to just do it with HTML...

Comment: is there any control to add or display, since we can get the file name from Fileinfo?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798867/text-under-an-image-button

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the ImageButton into a parent DIV element with the text label.  A small table with two rows and 1 cell would work well also.

Example:

```
Table table = new Table();
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
table.Controls.Add(row);
row.Controls.Add(cell);
cell.Controls.Add(imageButton);
row = new TableRow();
cell = new TableCell();
table.Controls.Add(row);
row.Controls.Add(cell);
cell.Text = "Image Text";
```

Comment: what is cell.Text = "Image Text"; supposed to do here?

Comment: Whatever you are defining as the name of the image.  Whether it is the filename or some other meta data that you have.

Comment: Are you adding the table to the panel controls instead of the image button.  Check the contents of your fi.Name.  Is the table object appearing in the Html source as you would expect?  Viewing the html source will help greatly.