# Adding an image and text both in asp.net button

Tags: asp.net, .net, button

I am looking for a solution where I will be able to add an image and text both in asp.net button.

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"/>
```

I am only able to specify text to the button, but how can I add an image as well to it?

Comment: you should be using  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx

Comment: Can I specify text and image both together in Image button?

Comment: Yes ofcourse. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.text.aspx

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Text is not visible, only image is visible in the button.

Comment: Try checking out this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262141/text-on-an-image-button-in-c-sharp-asp-net-3-5

Comment: An `ImageButton` doesn't have a visible text attribute. The one @Royi Namir references to is the `alt`-tag.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By default, ASP .Net doesn't have a button which can **render both image and text at the same time**. However, you can achieve in two ways.

### Using CSS

I prefer CSS because it is light weight, and you can style it whatever you want.

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
    .submit {
        border: 1px solid #563d7c;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px 10px 5px 25px;
        background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDCI4.png) 
            left 3px top 5px no-repeat #563d7c;
    }
</style>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Submit" CssClass="submit" />
```

### Third Party Control

It works right out of the box. However, you cannot change their style easily.

[image]

Use third party control like [Telerik RadButton](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/button/examples/embeddedicons/defaultcs.aspx).

*Last but not least if you want, you can implement a custom server control by yourself.*

Comment: thank you very much! At least we have some control over .net :/ Dont like using Telerik:)

Comment: this is helpful. But you also need to add additional property background-repeat:repeat-y; to make image look at left and not repeat

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple Solution, that works for me:

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnRun" Text="<i class='fa fa-home'></i> Search"
                                    CssClass="btn-success" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple Solution, that works for me:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="ClickMe" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClick="ClickMe_Click" style="text-decoration: none; color: #505050;">
    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="/Resources/Bitmaps/excel_24.png" style="margin-left:5px;" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Very neat and simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a font icon instead of an image.

**CSS**

```
.button {
   min-width:175px;
   border-radius:50px;
   background:none;
   outline:none;
   border:none;
   color:#fff;
   padding:15px 25px;
   margin-top:10px;
   background: rgba(115,84,178,1);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(115,84,178,1) 0%, rgba(115,84,178,0.95) 34%, rgba(115,84,178,0.95) 35%, rgba(96,107,192,0.91) 62%, rgba(84,160,231,0.85) 100%);
   background: -webkit-gradient(left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(115,84,178,1)), color-stop(34%, rgba(115,84,178,0.95)), color-stop(35%, rgba(115,84,178,0.95)), color-stop(62%, rgba(96,107,192,0.91)), color-stop(100%, rgba(84,160,231,0.85)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(115,84,178,1) 0%, rgba(115,84,178,0.95) 34%, rgba(115,84,178,0.95) 35%, rgba(96,107,192,0.91) 62%, rgba(84,160,231,0.85) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(115,84,178,1) 0%, rgba(115,84,178,0.95) 34%, rgba(115,84,178,0.95) 35%, rgba(96,107,192,0.91) 62%, rgba(84,160,231,0.85) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(115,84,178,1) 0%, rgba(115,84,178,0.95) 34%, rgba(115,84,178,0.95) 35%, rgba(96,107,192,0.91) 62%, rgba(84,160,231,0.85) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(115,84,178,1) 0%, rgba(115,84,178,0.95) 34%, rgba(115,84,178,0.95) 35%, rgba(96,107,192,0.91) 62%, rgba(84,160,231,0.85) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7354b2', endColorstr='#54a0e7', GradientType=1 );
}
```

You can remove the `background` and `filter` part in the class `button` in the above style. I just used it for the gradient background for the button.

**HTML**

```
<button runat="server" id="btnDownload" class="button" onserverclick="clickEvent">
    <i class="fa fa-download" style="font-size:20px;float:left;"></i> DOWNLOAD
</button>
```

Button looks like below.

[image]

[**Fiddle demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/udF6qN)

And even you can change the icon color by just adding color to the `<i>...</i>`. Something like below.

```
<button runat="server" id="btnDownload" class="button" onserverclick="clickEvent">
    <i class="fa fa-download" style="font-size:20px;float:left;color:#ff4444;"></i> 
        DOWNLOAD
</button>
```