# PushButton Icon in GridButtonColumn ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik

How to add icon in grid button column, apart from using `ButtonType="FontIconButton"`, but using `ButtonType="PushButton"`?

Here is my aspx code:

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="DeleteCommandColumn" ButtonType="PushButton" CommandName="Delete" ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to delete this?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow">
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Specify a `ButtonCssClass` in the css file

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="DeleteCommandColumn" ButtonType="PushButton" ButtonCssClass="btn-withpic" CommandName="Delete" ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to delete this?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow">
```

In the css file, specify padding and background:

```
.btn-withpic{
  padding: ....;
  background: url(../../xx.png) 
            left ()px top ()px 
}
```

A reference:[button with image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912432/adding-an-image-and-text-both-in-asp-net-button)